# Calculate the grid value for specific column using jquery in grails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an existing table where I have a column name `cost`. I want to add the values of `cost` using jquery when I click the submit button. But I don't have any idea about how to do it. Here is my grid.

[image]

and here is my code. At least I want to show an alert having the sum of the values of `cost` column.

```
<span class="button">
    <input name="clearFormButtonDetailOfficeDecoration"
                                class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="button"
                                onclick=" sumOfgrid();" value="Submit"/>
</span>
```

and jquery function

```
function sumOfgrid() {
        var summaryData = $("#jqgrid-grid-detailOfficeDecoration").jqxGrid('getcolumnaggregateddata', 'cost',  ['sum']);
         alert(summaryData);
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here replace "cost" with your 'cost' column class,

```
var sum = 0;

$(".cost").each(function() {

    var value = $(this).text();
    if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
      var sum=0;
      var myData = $('#jqgrid-grid-detailOfficeDecoration').jqGrid('getRowData');
     // var rowCount = $("#jqgrid-grid-detailOfficeDecoration").getGridParam("reccount");
     // alert(rowCount);
      var c =  Object.keys(myData).length;
      for (var i=0;i<c;i++){
          var mydata=parseFloat(myData[i].cost);
          sum+=mydata;
          //alert(myData[i].cost)

      }
      $("#totaldecorationcost").val(sum);

  });
```